# Can I alias the return type of a fuction

Tags: go, reflection, types

I have a function that returns an anonymous struct. This function is generated and so I cannot change the code or create a type for the return value.

```golang
func foo() struct {
    Prop int
} {
    result := new(struct {
        Prop int
    })
    result.Prop = 1
    return *result
}
```

In other places in the codebase, I want to define a function, `bar()` that accepts as an argument the return type of `foo()`

```golang
func bar(arg ReturnTypeOfFoo) {
    // ...
}
```

Can I do this without manually defining the `ReturnTypeOfFoo` type? Is there some kind of reflection I can do on `foo()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the same anonymous struct as the parameter type for `bar()`:

```
func bar(arg struct {
    Prop int
}) {
    fmt.Printf("Received: %+v\n", arg)
}
```

Then the following is valid code:

```
res := foo()
bar(res)
```

And outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/xleFrl8hNLz)):

```
Received: {Prop:1}
```

This is possible because the [call](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls) `bar(res)` is valid if all arguments are [assignable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) to the parameter types of `bar()`, and the anonymous struct return type of `foo()` is assignable to the anonymous struct parameter of `bar()`.

If you need this to be dynamic (e.g. the result type of `foo()` may change when re-generated), you may use the [`go/parser`](https://golang.org/pkg/go/parser/) package to parse the generated source, and generate `bar()` with identical parameter type, idiomatically executed when `go generate` is run. You should make this part of the generation process that generates / changes `foo`, so `foo` and `bar` will be in sync.

Comment: Adding a 2nd generation step is a great recommendation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Can I do this without manually defining the ReturnTypeOfFoo type?

No, because ...

> Is there some kind of reflection I can do on foo()?

No. You cannot use reflection at compile time.